# What is the concordance rate for schizophrenia in monozygotic and dizygotic twins?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, genetics, nature-nurture, twin-study

What is general level of concordance for twins and is it higher for monozygotic twins?
What research is available on this?

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia article seems to provide a summary of this information with links to the primary literature

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causes_of_schizophrenia#Genetics

> Concordance rates between monozygotic twins vary in different studies,
>   approximately 50%; whereas dizygotic twins was 17%. Some twin
>   studies (Koskenvuo et al; Hoeffer et al) have found rates as low as 11.0%–13.8% among
>   monozygotic twins, and 1.8%–4.1% among dizygotic twins, however.

#### References

- Koskenvuo M, Langinvainio H, Kaprio J, Lönnqvist J, Tienari P; Langinvainio; Kaprio; Lönnqvist; Tienari (1984). "Psychiatric hospitalization in twins". Acta Genet Med Gemellol (Roma) 33 (2): 321–32. PMID 6540965.
- Hoeffer A, Pollin W; Pollin (November 1970). "Schizophrenia in the NAS-NRC panel of 15,909 veteran twin pairs". Arch Gen Psychiatry 23 (5): 469–77. doi:10.1001/archpsyc.1970.01750050085012. PMID 5478575.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the [Meta-Analysis of Twin Correlations and Heritability (MATCH) website](http://match.ctglab.nl/#/home) which is fully interactive and searchable.

The following image is a screenshot from their results on Schizophrenia, which shows that generally the concordance (here reported as correlation) of diagnosis between MZ twins is generally quite a bit higher than across DZ twins:

[image: all = both sexes; ss = same sex; m = male; f = female; mz = monozygotic; dz = dizygotic; dos = ?]